# Grafana 8 alert API not providing instance details

Tags: grafana, grafana-api, grafana-alerts

I am having a requirement where I need to fetch all the alerting instances with details like IP Address. I used the api url ***/api/prometheus/grafana/api/v1/rules*** to get all the alerts. But in case of dashboards with multiple instances, the response does not have the alerting instance details like IP address/Hostname, but the variable name ***$instance*** is present. Is it possible to get the IP address of the alerting instance rather than the variable name.